# How to instantiate a referenced object in Spring Boot by means of annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

How to instantiate a referenced object in Spring Boot by means of annotations?

```
public class Sign {
    private static final List<String> KEYS = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        KEYS.add(HeaderKey.XCaAppkey);
        KEYS.add(HeaderKey.XCaEncryption);
        KEYS.add(HeaderKey.XCaNonce);
        KEYS.add(HeaderKey.XCaTimestamp);
        KEYS.add(HeaderKey.XServiceId);
        KEYS.add(HeaderKey.XServiceMethod);
        KEYS.add(HeaderKey.XCaSignature);
    }
    private HttpEntity<String> httpEntity;
    public Sign(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity) {
        this.httpEntity = httpEntity;
    }
    public String encode() {
        List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
        parts.add("requestBody=" + httpEntity.getBody());
        KEYS.stream().forEach(key -> {
            parts.add(key + "="+httpEntity.getHeaders().getFirst(key));
        });
        String value = StringUtils.join(parts, "&");
        return DigestUtils.md5Hex(value);
    }
}

public class ApiClient {
    /*
    *
    * */
         @Autowired
         private Sign sign;

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);
//Sign sign=new Sign(entity);  how to choose new object and automatic import
        String caSignature=sign.encode();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `@Service` or `@Component` annotation on `Sign` class.

Comment: thank u very much.Approve, reject, or improve edits suggested by users
I won’t ask such a silly question again, I should think independently.